# character array triangle having characters seperated with spaces in C language

Tags: c, arrays, char, geometry

im trying to create this kind of a triangle in C language which is a right angled triangle and
the text is separated or delimited with spaces.
it should print
first line: this, second line: this is, third line :this is the , fourth line : this is the best . and so on

my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char msg[]="this is the best way to spend time";
    int inn, out, i=0, max;
    max=(sizeof(msg)/sizeof(int))+1;
    char *output;
    char *spc=" ";
    output=strtok(msg,spc);
    for(out=1;out<max;out++){
        for(i=0;i<out && output != NULL;i++){
            if(output!=" ")
                printf("%s ", output);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `max=sizeof(msg)/sizeof(int);` this is wrong, `msg` is an array of chars (not an array of ints), and don't forget to include `string.h` for `strtok`

Comment: It would help if you showed what the output should look like. It's not very  clear (*...kind of a triangle...* isn't enough).

Comment: the output should look like this

Comment: (first line) this (second line) this is (third line) this is the (fourth line) this is the best  (fifth line) this is the best way

Comment: @deeraf : update your question instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char msg[]="this is the best way to spend time";
    int i, spc;

    for(spc = 1 ;; ++spc){
        int count_spc = 0;
        for(i=0; msg[i]; ++i){
            if(msg[i] == ' '){
                ++count_spc;
                if(count_spc == spc){
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf("%c", msg[i]);
        }
        if(msg[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you try an make it without the break; i tried but i'm getting all kinds of errors, not compilation errors but errors still.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `max=sizeof(msg)/sizeof(int)` is wrong, it should be `max=sizeof(msg);`, since your string consists of `char`s and not `int`s and `sizeof(char)` is always 1. However, this is not needed as we will see later on.

Furthermore, you should check the man pages for `strtok`.
Especially this part:

> The strtok() function parses a string into a
>   sequence of tokens. On the first call to strtok() the string to be
>   parsed should be specified in str. In each subsequent call that should
>   parse the same string, str should be NULL.

Therefore, you should call `output=strtok(msg,spc)` once for every line of your triangle, and then `strtok(NULL,spc)` once for each word in each line of the triangle.

Also, you should note that when there are no more tokens, `strtok` returns a NULL pointer, and hence you do not need to know the size of the string, but check for a NULL pointer to terminate your program.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the fact that each string must be emitted from the start for each next space:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int _, char **ptr)
{
    char msg[198] = "this is the worst way to spend your time";
    ptr[0] = msg, ptr[1] = msg;
    while (*ptr[0])
    {
        if (*ptr[0] == ' ')
        {
            memmove (ptr[0]+1, ptr[1], strlen(ptr[1])+1);
            *ptr[0]++ = 012;
            ptr[2] = ptr[0];
            ptr[0] = ptr[1]+((ptr[0]-ptr[1])<<1);
            ptr[1] = ptr[2];
        }
        ptr[0]++;
    }
    return printf ("%s\n", msg);
}
```

Comment: Works for me, as I have a habit of trying before I post. But don't feel bad. *Your* code is not working for me either.

Comment: It works when compiled with gcc on Windows. Let me check tonight, I'll see if it works on my Mac as well. In the mean time, "not working" = "not compiling"? If it does compile, try running it with a few random arguments.

Comment: It works on OS X as well. (There was a *small* chance it would not, as using 'unassigned' pointers from the `argv` array doesn't seem to be documented -- at least, not easy to find --, hence my suggestion to try with a number of arguments.)

Comment: What reason that can be used `ptr[2]` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: good question. It works on both Windows and Mac OS X, suggesting that there is *some* extra space reserved for the arguments pointers. I could not find any details on if, and how much, though.

Comment: Is it not the only one for NULL? (It has been requested by the standard. but 2 isn't.)

Comment: It's like saying that  i could use because there are areas of surplus, even beyond the range of the array.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I could not find any reason to assume one **cannot** use `argv` this way. I could not readily find it (clearly) stated in any standards; but if you do have a lead on where to look, I'll gladly read it. Note that this pointer stuff is unrelated to the inner workings of my algorithm. My `ptr` usage can safely and easily be replaced with a more common pointer declaration inside `main`.

Comment: [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup 2** _argv[argc] shall be a null pointer._  _My ptr usage can safely and easily be replaced_  i know.

Comment: However, please note that it is not a must.